# Xamarin.iOS Build Step for Team City server

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, teamcity, build-server, xbuild

I am using a Team City (10.0.4) server for my Xamarin Build Steps. 
I have set up a buil agent on a macmini which is building my whole solution (Anrdoid, iOS). 
The build process is invoked via command line:

```
xbuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:IpaPackageDir="[mydir]" /p:BuildIpa=true /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /t:"Build" MyApp.iOS.csproj
```

The build process is working perfectly fine even if I am not sure if the built files should really be located in the work folder of my build agent.

The actually problem is that I am not getting a .ipa file from the build step which I actually need to keep on working.

The build agent is installed on a MacMini with OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer by myself. 
There are 2 options which have to be set:

```
xbuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="iPhone" /p:OutputPath="path/to/dir" /p:IpaPackageDir="path/to/dir" /p:BuildIpa=true /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /t:"Build" myApp.iOS.csproj
```

The Platform and the outputdirectory have to be specified then it works perfectly fine.